# Get IP from DHCP server from other machine in Internal Network

Tags: linux, networking, router, debian, dhcp

I have two virtual machines:

1. Debian (Router) with one Bridged Adapter and three Internal Network adapters
2. Ubuntu with one Internal Network adapter

I installed on Debian DHCP server, I'd like Ubuntu machine to get IP address from the DHCP server that is installed on Debian. But it is not working.

My configuration files:

Debian

```
/etc/network/interfaces

#   The loopback network interface auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#   The primary network interface allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

#   servers
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet
static address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

#   administration auto eth2

iface eth2 inet
static address 192.168.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

#   hotel guests
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet
static address 192.168.3.1 
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

```
subnet 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   eth3;
   range 192.168.3.2 192.168.3.254;
   option routers 192.168.3.1;
   option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.2;
}
```

restart dhcp and networking - no error

Ubuntu machine:

```
/etc/network/interfaces

auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

next, `service networking restart` I get this message:

[image]

IP address is not assigned. Why? 
Give more information?

Comment: any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that the NIC `eth3` is attached to the same internal network as your  Ubuntu Guest? Because of problems in NIC naming, you might very well have that `eth3` is attached to a different internal network than your Ubuntu VM.

One way to solve this is to have  your DHCP server listening on all internal interfaces, then the Ubuntu VM would probably get a DHCP offer.

Another solution is to specify, for the 4 adapters of the Debian VM, four different hardware implementations, then write appropriate udev rules to attach them to the appropriate names, `eth1`, `eth2`, `eth3`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. How to put DHCP server to listen on all internal interfaces?

Comment: @lukassz Which DHCP server are you using? Dnsmasq?  Isc-dhcp-server?

Comment: Isc-dhcp-server

Comment: @lukassz Then modify the file `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` to contain a line like `INTERFACES="eth1 eth2 ..."`.

Comment: I do not mind it at this on eth1, eth2 (debian machine) addresses are set static?

Comment: @lukassz No, no problem at all.